# What is the keyboard shortcut for converting code to uppercase in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to big-query and I needed to know the shortcut for converting a text or line text into uppercase in macbook. In Teradata and others I used to do ctrl + U. I do not see any shortcuts for such in Google documentation. If anyone knows please let me know. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can get to this operation:

1. highlight the text you want uppercased
2. press F1, the command palette will come up
3. use the quick filter to type: upper and choose and by selecting it will run

most used items will be remembered and will be offered first
AFAIK there is no shortcut assigned to this operation

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to do this in a macbook pro?

Comment: `F1` works for me on PC and MacBook [Pro] . If your Function Keys are customized and `F1` does not work as described in answer  - use following - Highlight text >> Right Click >> Choose Command Palette from Contextual Menu >> ...